# SensioFrameworkExtraBundle vs JMSSecurityExtraBundle

Tags: security, symfony, symfony-2.4

I was trying to evaluate the best among [JMSSecurityExtraBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle) and [SensioFrameworkExtraBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html). First is a popular security bundle and the other listed in symfony2 website.

While both provide the annotations to secure the methods of a controller via `@Secure` in JMS and `@Security` in Sensio, JMS security bundle provides more security options [See here](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/master/configuration)

I would like to ask the community which is the best bundle for Symfony 2.4

Comment: I guess this was down voted because `@Security` is the annotation provided by Sensio bundle and not `@Secure`. Also `@Security` annotation is something new in Symfony2.4 only and not Symfony 2.3. My question is regarding Symfony2.4 only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@Security` annotation was added to `SensioFrameworkExtraBundle` in version `2.4` of the bundle !

That means it does **NOT** work with a Symfony version < 2.4 because this version of the bundle requires the `ExpressionLanguage` component that was added in Symfony 2.4 to work.

Have a look at the bundle's [composer.json](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/composer.json#L14).

Further the `@Security` annotation only works for controller classes because the check is performed in a [subscriber](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/2.3/EventListener/ControllerListener.php#L51) that listens for the `kernel.controller` event.

The `JMSSecurityExtraBundle` can be configured to work with all defined services (not just controller classes). Further it ...

- works with symfony versions < 2.4
- provides slightly more features (i.e. the [`is_expr_granted`](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/1.2/expressions#twig-usage) twig function for symfony versions < 2.4)
- is less performant (due to it's architecture)
- uses a different license (Apache instead of MIT)

Hope that clarifies it a bit.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I was looking at this url http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html Which shows `@Security` annotation because of which I thought it works for `Symfony2.3`

Comment: Thanks for this piece of information. "The `JMSSecurityExtraBundle` can be configured to work with all defined services (not just controller classes)"

Comment: I have created an [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/3492) on github. The misleading occurence in the 2.3 docs should hopefully be fixed soon. :)